# How to implement inherited abstract method?

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I try to implement 2 interfaces

```
public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity implements
OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {
```

but for `OnCheckedChangeListener` I get this error

```
The type SecondScreenActivity must implement the inherited abstract method
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton, boolean)
```

How can I implement inherited abstract method? I never met this before...

Comment: You need to do some Java/OOP homeworks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You extended a class which has abstract methods ( methods without body) in order to extend this class you must implement the methods.

to implement a method you must name it the same way, with the same parameters, or click ctrl+1 on the error line in eclipse and select implement abstract methods.

Answer (score 1):

To implement a method add it to your class with the same signature. Here we need a method called `onCheckedChange` with parameters `CompoundButton` and `boolean`. So, add a method such as:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean checked){
    //your code
}
```

Comment: One tool to help make sure you have the proper parameters and spelling is to preface the method with `@Override`.  That tells the compiler that you are trying to override or implement a method and it looks for some common errors.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "CompoundButton", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
 - Syntax error on token "boolean", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
 - The method onCheckedChanged() of type SecondScreenActivity must override or implement a supertype 
  method